# PreferenceActivity extension to support all standard preference types

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

It is known that `PreferenceActivity` and its `EditText-`, `List-`, and other `***Preference` classes support only preferences of the type `String`. It's not clear why (in fact, this degrades Android's standard `SharedPreferences` badly), but it is so, and there seems nothing to do with this.

I'd like to support all standard types of shared preferences (`Boolean`, `Float`, `Int`, `Long`, `String`, `String Set`) seamlessly, and retain look and feel provided by the `PreferenceActivity`. One of the cases when it may be necessary is the case when some preferences do already exist in an application, and they are not strings.

Of course, there is a straightforward approach with conversion of existing preferences into strings, but it's ugly and a kind of last resort. Another way is to create an activity from scratch which mimics `PreferenceActivity` functionality and handles all types. This seems having too much routine work.

Does someone know and can suggest an existing implementation of such extended `***Preference` descendants supporting all standard types? `EditTextPreference`, and `ListPreference` templatized to required type would be enough for beginning.

If there exist some other ways to work in UI with preferences of different types easily, please, mention them as well.

Comment: Your fundamental assumption is not quite correct -- `CheckboxPreference` uses a `boolean`.

Comment: @CommonsWare, pardon me, could you be more specific?

Comment: `CheckBoxPreference` stores a `boolean` in `SharedPreferences`. You are claiming that it stores a `String` in `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: @CommonsWare, ok, I'll correct my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly easy to create your own MyPreferenceActivity, isn't it? In that activity, you can implement all types of preferences that you want, and even invent new ones. It's good programming practice to wrap the standard SharedPreferences in an application preferences layer, so your application is not dependent on the implementation of preferences, other than in this wrapping class. In that class, you can create every type of preference you want, using the standard preferences that SharedPreferences has. Or you can store them in a database, or in a file, or in the cloud. If you use SharedPreferences in your activities, it's hard to switch to an implementation that uses a db or the cloud.

Comment: IMO, it's easy conceptually, but requires a wealth of routine work (I mentioned this in the question). On the other hand, this is presumably a popular task. So there could be ready-made preference classes for some data types. I don't want to delve into an implementation of something that already exist.

Comment: I've done the work once. I use the code in most projects I do. And sometimes I adjust it, make it better, more flexible. Same is true for other code, like image loaders or http code.